# Elevated drainage holes in a plastic pot

Tags: containers

I bought a plastic pot today that has three drainage holes. The drainage holes are about an inch above the bottom, as in the picture below.

What is the reasoning behind this? Is it better if I drill another hole at the bottom (equidistant from these 3 holes at the center), or it wouldn't matter?

I plan to plant Tulasi in it (Holy Basil), which I read won't tolerate damp soil.

[image: Pot with elevated drainage holes]

Comment: I have myself wondered the same after seeing similar containers in Berlin. They were about 1m x 0.25m and the drainage was even more raised.